# Changing submit button text value per form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm rendering a form on a few different pages, such as: `edit, new, show`. Now on the submit button it says: `"update post"` and `"create post"`. I know that there is a way to add custom text to the buttons `<%= f.submit "Text" %>`. But because i'm rendering the form it shows that value on each of the pages. So i'm wondering if there is a way where i can add the custom text value per page, without having to copy the whole form itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Rails built-i I18n (internationalization) module](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html):

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      post:
        create: "Toss me bottle to the sea!"
        update: "Arg! Now she be a spellin' straight."
```

You need to remove the text from submit button in order for it to be translated:

```
<%= f.submit %>
```